# Is there a minimum number of people needed for an aircraft pushback?

Tags: jet, pushback

[image: A total of 6 people in this pushback (2 in the truck)]

This seems a bit wasteful. Is there a legal requirement for a minimum number of people and if so, on what basis does this vary? (airline, airport, aircraft type, etc)

Comment: If you don't have "wing/tail walkers" you [get accidents](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Accident_and_Serious_Incident_Reports:_GND#Aircraft_Push_Back). Better to waste some time than damage some aircraft.

Comment: BTW, when you ask if there is a "legal" requirement, you need to tell us what country you are talking about. This may be different for the US and Botswana, for example.

Comment: Hmm. I think I'd be curious to know even _if_ there was a legal requirement in _any_ country.

Comment: @Ron Beyer standard pushback in my base (Helsinki, Finland) is done with one person on the ground, in the tractor to be exact. We haven't had any pushback accidents that I'm aware of. We have an excellent safety culture and very good training for everyone involved. Wing walkers might improve safety, but their absence does not automatically lead to accidents

Comment: @Sami The stands at Helsinki are set up such that you aren't pushing back into other aircraft, so the chances of having those types of accidents are much lower. Look at an airport like [O'Hare](https://www.google.com/maps/place/O'Hare+International+Airport/@41.9741255,-87.9045642,499m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x880fb4276a7762f3:0x511747070259ad4b!8m2!3d41.9741625!4d-87.9073214), where there are "alleys" that the aircraft park in, this pretty much requires it. Even my small airport has wing-walkers just for safety reasons.

Comment: Regarding your picture, some of the people are probably trainees

Comment: It's not just on pushback... this happened, probably because no-one was assigned to keep watch where it mattered. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-UGnbtX67M

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on the airline.  At minimum, you need one driving the tractor, and in unconfined areas with nothing to run into, this is sufficient.  In confined areas operators almost always require wing walkers to clear the tips, and someone at the tail if backing into a confined space or to make sure the pushback stays within any boundaries.

So the answer is, anywhere from 1 to 4, depending on the situation and the airline's internal policy.  Insurance requirements will have an influence on this in a lot of cases because the results of screw-ups are usually just insurance damage claims with nobody getting hurt.

Comment: One can easily cause damage worth a years salary of a wingwalker by not using one.